# using one Qcombobox to set value to several labels, C++

Tags: c++, qt

im trying to set the value from a combobox to multiple Qlabels, the idea is to populate the QcomboBox with all the values, then according to the number, (ejem 15.6) the corresponding label should change the problem is, theres too many of them to simply use a switch of something similar, but all the names of the labels are similar, HumSec_val156 corresponds to 15.6 the main idea was to use

```
Silo* silo = new Silo;
QString number = widget.QComboBox->currentText();
QString nameOfLabel = "HumSec_val"; 
nameOfLabel.append(QString::number(number));
silo->findchild<QLabel*>(nameOfLabel)->setText(valuefromCombobox);
```

but everytime it simply return an empty string, i did try using somthing simplier like

```
widget.nameOfLabel->setText(valuefromComboBox);
```

but nameOfLabel its just a qstring so i can mix it with the code generated from designer. Any idea what can i do? do i need to create something like a scoped enum or similar?

below i add a picture of what im doing

[image]

Comment: Don't you have to call `findchild` on your existing UI window / widget container, and not on a brand-new empty one?

Comment: i usually do the follow ```widget.QlabelName->setText();```and works fine, the issue here its the name of labels, they only differ by number and i cant access the usual name, thats why strugle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I would do something like this, I would probably create a QHash<QString, QLabel*> and use that as a cache to find the matching QLabel for each name.

Declaration:

```
QHash<QString, QLabel*> m_hash
```

Storing value:

```
m_hash[labelName] = labelPtr;
```

Reading value:

```
QLabel* labelPtr = m_hash.value(labelName, nullptr);
if (labelPtr)
{
    // Access label
}
```

When you remove a label remember to remove it from the hash as well:

```
const QString key = m_hash.key(labelPtr);
m_hash.remove(key);
```